# Оборот с "как". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить запятые и подчеркнуть грамматическую основу в предложениях:

**1. Был лес как сон и сад как сон под каждой колкой ёлкою.**
Является ли "как сон" сравнительным оборотом или входит в состав сказуемого?

**2. Она, как рыба, там блестела, и было дерево как есть.**
"Дерево" подлежащее, а "было как есть" сказуемое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Был лес **как сон** и сад **как сон** под каждой колкой ёлкою.*

Это сложносочиненное предложение с двумя основами:  *Лес был как сон и сад (был) как сон.* Запятая перед И не ставится при наличии общего обстоятельства.
Сказуемое составное именное,  именная часть выражена сравнительным оборотом.

2. *Она, **как рыба**, там блестЕла, и было дерево **как есть**.*

Сравнительный оборот «как рыба» обособляется, если ударение падает на глагол.  Вариант без обособлении тоже возможен, если ударением выделен сравнительный оборот, авторский выбор: *Она **как рЫба** там блестела, и было дерево **как есть.***

3. Оборот ***«как есть»*** не обособляется,  здесь его можно рассматривать как устойчивое сочетание. *Дерево **как есть*** – это такое дерево, каким его обычно представляют, каким оно бывает.

Сравнить: *Жизнь **как  есть**.*

Вся жизнь вместилась в него: ее жизнь, и чужая, и вообще ничья ― просто жизнь **как есть.** [А.Берсенева. (2003-2005)]

Всё **как есть** расписала, всю нашу несчастную жизнь… [И. Грекова. Перелом (1987)]

Вот он весь **как есть**, ― говорит Коля. [Б. Окуджава. (1962)]

Из словаря: ЕСТЬ. 1. к Быть. 2. (как **неизменяемая связка в составном именном сказ.**). Являться, представлять собой в действительности. / (в сочет. с вопросит. местоим.: как, чем). *Искусство должно показывать жизнь, как она е.  Жизнь, как она е., всё равно прекрасна.*

Comment: Очень подробный ответ. Все понятно. Спасибо огромное.